# XAMPP Invalid authentication method set in configuration: ‘cookie’

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have read all the possible fixes for the above issue when trying to get XAMPP working. Nothing has worked and I need to find an answer to get it working for a college course.

I am running a Mac OS X 10.11.6 and downloaded the XAMPP version 5.6.40. Then I open http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ go to user accounts and change the root password on for local host.

Then I go to the file config.inc.php and change 'config' to 'cookie' and also change the password. Then I restart the servers try to log back in but it gives the above error message and doesn't let me enter credentials. Some students in my class have done it the exact same way and it has worked for them.

I have looked at and tried many possible fixes as I can but with no success.

Comment: Try to clear browser's cache and cookies, maybe it will help. Also try with blank '' password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Then you can set the user and password to blank, as using `cookie` makes phpMyAdmin throw a login page where you are expected to enter the userid and password in the login dialog.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

> It would also be worth refreshing your browser cache after making this change.
>
> Thats CRTL+F5
>
> Dont forget to restart Apache after making this change